# MVP pattern on .net

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms

I want to understand on how to implement a MVP pattern on .net using windows form.
In the future I want to use the created pattern on web.

My problem is that I'm not sure if I do it right.

What I did is some presenter I attach multiple view to it, which means that I cannot used that presenter without specifying first all the views that are attached to it.

```
public class ScorePresenter{
    private IScoreView _scoreView;
    private IClientView _clientView;        

    public ScorePresenter()
    {
    }

    public void AttachView(IScoreView view){
        this._scoreView = view;
    }

    public void AttachView(IClientView view){
        this._clientView = view;
    }

    public void Create(Model model){
        try{
            //create code here                

            this._clientView.Reload();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }

}

public class ClientPresenter(){
    private IClientView _clientView;

    public ClientPresenter(){

    }

    public void AttachView(IClientView view){
        this._clientView = view;
    }
}


public interface IClientView{
    void Reload();
}

public interface IScoreView{

}
```

usage

client form vb.net

```
Public Class ClientForm
    Implements IClientView

    Private _clientPresenter As ClientPresenter

    Public Sub ClientForm_Load() Handles Me.Load
        Me._clientPresenter = new ClientPresenter()
        Me._clientPresenter.AttachView(Me)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Reload Implements IClientView.Reload
           Reload code here
    End Sub

    Public Sub ScoreButton_Click() Handles ScoreButton.Click
           Dim frmScoreForm as New ScoreForm
           frmScoreForm.MyParent = Me
           frmScoreForm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

End Class
```

score form vb.net

```
Public Class ScoreForm
    Implements IScoreView

    Private _scorePresenter As ScorePresenter

    Public Sub ScoreForm_Load() Handles Me.Load
          Me._scorePresenter = new ScorePresenter()

          Me._scorePresenter.AttachView(Me)
          Me._scorePresenter.AttachView(Me._myParent)
    End Class

    Private _myParent as Object
    Public WriteOnly Property MyParent As Object
          Set(value As Object)
               Me._myParent = value
          End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

on this code client form is the main form if i clicked the score button on client form it will show the score form

on score form if i create or manipulate data in it it will call the client form reload
and client form will also update it's data on the view

what I see in this one is that I cannot use ScorePresenter alone right? Is that a bad design? if yes is there other way to achieve what I want to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you want to communicate views in a sense that changes in one of them should update the other.

If this is the case, your approach is wrong.

First, your presenter should not manage both views. A reasonable rule in mvp is to have a presenter for each view so that you have 1-1 correspondence between views and presenters.

Then, the communication between presenters is done with messaging, for example with the **Event Aggregator**. Presenters subscribe to events and other presenters publish events. This way your presenters are completely decoupled from each other, instead they are only coupled to the eventing engine. And publications-subscriptions let you create **implicit** dependencies.

In other words, if the data in one view changes, the view uses its presenter to raise an event. Some other subscribing presenters catch the event and call updating methods on their views.

In your specific case you should

- introduce another presenter, the ClientPresenter
- learn an existing or create a custom implementation of an event aggregator
- introduce the event aggreegator in both presenters
- create event classes and wire up subscriptions in presenters
- raise events when appropriate in one of your presenters

Comment: Event Aggregator is new for me. I looked an example on the web and I found this one. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample

Comment: http://www.ronaldwidha.net/2010/05/31/a-simple-example-of-the-webformsmvp-cross-presenter-messaging/

Comment: There is also one in Prism.